# Electric field outside superconducting wire

Tags: electric-fields, superconductivity

I understand that in a superconducting wire you have no electric field and no magnetic field(or at least these enter by a small amount given by the London penetration depth) and the current resides mostly on the outer layer of the wire. I wanted to ask what the electric field outside the superconducting wire.

Comment: If there is no electric field in the wire and it's a constant current, I don't see why there would be any electric field outside the wire. Were you thinking otherwise?

Comment: i actually looked it up earlier and you can use gauss's law as with a usual wire and get a radial electric field outside. This is since the the enclosed charge is equal in the superconducting and non superconducting state(for an equivalent current of course)

Comment: A wire, superconducting or not, does not normally have a net charge.

Comment: yes you are right, i was thinking of a line of charge, but that's different to a wire